# Enter a variable in the 'category_name' parameter

Tags: categories, wp-query, loop, variables, get-the-title

Is it possible to use a variable for the `'category_name'` parameter?

I have three pages: red, yellow, and blue. I have multiple posts that are categorized in three categories: red, yellow, and blue. On the red page, I wish to display information from the posts in the red category; the same goes for yellow and blue.

I can do this easily if I create three different page templates with these `$args` at the beginning of the loops:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'red'
);  

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

or

```
'category_name' => 'yellow'
```

or

```
'category_name' => 'blue'
```

Rather than make three separate page templates, is it possible to create one, in which the `'category_name'` parameter is set to the page's title (so the 'red' page would result in 'red' being dynamically set to the `'category_name'` parameter)?

While this doesn't work, hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
$title = the_title()

$args = array(
    'category_name' => $title
);
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: @PieterGoosen Can you explain why you think this is a duplicate? That other question doesn't ask about variables for the 'category_name' parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can pass the variable in `category_name`. But I think it should be `get_the_title()` instead of `the_title()`.

```
$title = get_the_title();

$args = array(
    'category_name' => $title
);
```

Try this. But remember `category_name` only accepts category slug, not category name.

You can also use following method if your page title/slug are different. And I think it's better.

```
if ( is_page( 'Page Name One' ) ) {

    $cat_title = 'red'; // should be category slug

} elseif ( is_page( 'Page Name Two' ) ) {

    $cat_title = 'yellow'; // should be category slug

} elseif ( is_page( 'Page Name Three' ) ) {

    $cat_title = 'blue'; // should be category slug

}

$args = array(
    'category_name' => $cat_title
);
```

Comment: Bravo! Thank you so much. This answers my question precisely.